# How to select the latest or next element of a list with buttons

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make a little website I need to do for a lesson, we need to select items in a list and I have 2 arrows to select the item below or after the current item.

Here is an exemple:

[image]

So if I want to go back it needs to select "Gratin de knöpfli".

I had the idea to select it with an id but i really don't know how to do it.

PHP

```php
<?php

    function lectureRecette($fichier){
        $contenu=file_get_contents($fichier);
        echo "<br><br>Contenu du fichier $fichier : <br><pre>$contenu</pre>";
    }

    function compteurFichier($ext){
        $rep = glob('./recettes/*.'.$ext);
        $compteur = count($rep);
        return $compteur;
    }

    function afficherListe(){

        if($dossier = opendir('./recettes')){
            while(false !== ($fichier = readdir($dossier))){
                if($fichier != '.' && $fichier != '..'){
                    $nb_fichier += 1;
                    $nom_fichier = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $fichier);
                    echo '<option value="'.$fichier.'" name='.$fichier.'>'.$nom_fichier.'</option>';

                }
            }
        }
    }

    function afficheRecette($fichierSelectionne){
        $file='./recettes/'.$fichierSelectionne;
        $contenu=file_get_contents($file);
        echo "<pre>$contenu</pre>";
    }
    $recette = $_POST['recette_select'];
?>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!-- Partie HTML (construction mixte - statique et dynamique) -->
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta charset="iso-8859-1" />
        <meta name="description" content="i-ct, module 133, web, css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images\top.jpg", align="center", width="100%">
        </div>

        <div id="liste">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Recettes dispo:</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            <label for="recette_liste"></label>
                            <form method="post">
                        <select name="recette_select" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <?php
                                afficherListe();
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </form>
                </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div id="contenu">
            <?php
                afficheRecette($recette);
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <a href="https://www.google.ch"><img src="icones\back.png", align="left", height="50", width="50">
            <a href="https://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.basic-syntax.comments.php"><img src="icones\home.png", align="center", size="16", height="50", width="50">
            <a href="https://www.color-hex.com/color/ffffe0"><img src="icones\go.png", align="right", size="16", height="50", width="50">

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!--                         Fin de la partie HTML                                      -->
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

CSS

```
*{
    font-family: verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

header{
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

#liste{
    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

#contenu{
    display:block;
    background: #FFFFE0;

}

#footer{
    text-align: center;
    background: yellow;

}
```

I expect it to simply go backward and forward in the list, any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you seeking a php or js solution.  Javascript seems sensible to me.  There are non regex ways or trimming the extension from a filename.

Comment: Mainly PHP since normally we learn about PHP and yeah i know but since i know a bit regex prefered to use it

Comment: Look at your `afficheRecette($recette);` and `afficherListe();` methods. With `$recette` you already seem to know the current recipe you are seeing. Therefore, use those and create a method that tells you the previous and next `$recette` and POST that back.

Comment: how are your recipes stored? is it just text? do you do something with that text? for example convert all those values into an array? if yes you could iterate trough that array and find your current and the previous or next recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `$fichierSelectionne` into `afficherListe` function and make item which has equal `$fichier` `selected="selected"`:

```
function afficherListe($fichierSelectionne = null) {
    if($dossier = opendir('./recettes')) {
        while(false !== ($fichier = readdir($dossier))) {
            if($fichier != '.' && $fichier != '..') {
                $nb_fichier += 1;
                $nom_fichier = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $fichier);
                echo '<option value="'.$fichier.'" name='.$fichier.' '.($fichier == $fichierSelectionne ? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$nom_fichier.'</option>';

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need $fichierSelectionne as you already have the current recipe in $recette

Comment: Perhaps, but I think that explicit passing of param is better for readability.

Comment: And how do i add the action to the arrows?

Comment: You can add it as a get parameter:`?page=some-page` and then get it inside the function via `$_GET['page']`